# How to send many commands to shell and wait for the command behind ends

Tags: shell, command-line

I have around 20 commands and I have to send all of this to Unix shell and copy the result, but I don't know how to do it.

I am not sure about what shell I have, because it is a small program connected to Mobile Network Managment, and with this small program we have access to send commands by line and recive the results by scream, for that reason I cannot use scripts for sending the commmands.

**Command 1** - Connect with a server.

Wait until command 1 finish

**Command 2**- Update all the information from server 1 finish

Wait.

**Command 3**. Get some parameter.

... and more such commands.

I **tried** with `cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3`
**and** `cmd1 & cmd2 & cmd3` and `cmd1;cmd2`

The problem is with `cmd1` its connected to a RNC(Network element) and takes aroud 15 seconds, after that `cmd2` has sense.
but just work for the first cmd. Any clue, how to run this?

Comment: Use a script? Or `&&` between commands.

Answer (score 24):

Usually just `cmd1;cmd2;cmd3;cmd4` (if you wanted to write it on one line), or using `cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3 && cmd4` if you don't want to run cmd3 when cmd2 fails.

Alternatively to `;` you can just write one command per line.

```
cmd1
cmd2
cmd3
cmd4
```

If you want the commands to run in parallel in background, you can also use

```
cmd1 &
cmd2 &
cmd3 &
cmd4 &
wait # for cmd1-4 to finish
```

Either of those methods can also be put in a shell script. There is little difference between what you write in a shell script and what you write in the actual shell itself.

Comment: MM the problem its when I send **cmd1** it really have to finish around 6 seconds, the problem its when it send **cmd2** and **cmd1** its still procesing it fails.

Comment: In the `cmd1;cmd2` case (or `cmd1 && cmd2` for that matter) cmd2 won't run until cmd1 has exited (and thus presumably finished). So there should not be any problem - please rephrase your question, or provide an example that people can actually reproduce.

Comment: Ok I am gonna modify the question. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into `sleep`, if your environment allows it. The complete sequence would then be something like `cmd1 && sleep 10s && cmd2`.
Here is the relevant [man page for sleep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sleep).

Comment: sleep/waiting is only useful if you deterministically know how long the previous program (which might spawn backgrounded process) takes to finish and exit (IE The Halting Problem) OR if you guarantee that you want to interrupt and run your second command after the interval has passed, which might happen if the two are asynchronous but you still want to some time in between them.

Most likely though, its not what you want.

Practically speaking, it might work. But it's not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a script, a file containing the commands to run one after the other, like:

```
#!/bin/sh

command-01
command-02
...
command-20
```

The first line (shebang) tells to run the following commands using `/bin/sh`, make the file executable (`chmod u+x your-little-script`) then you can run it by `./my-little-script`. This way you won't leave some step out ;-)

Read the manual for the shell, it provides a full programming language. Check out `bash(1)` if that is what is available, or else the Korn shell `ksh(1)`. They offer lots of useful features for controlling the flow of control in scripts (or interactively, for that matter).

Comment: Thanks but I cant use scritps.

Comment: Why? In any case, unless this is a _very_ fascist environment, you should be able to source the script: `source your-little-script` (or `. your-little-script` for short).

Comment: Becuase, I havent directly access to the unix system I have like a mini program what just permite to execute cmd in lines and get the result by scream, and for the use Im gonna use with this commands its not practical to use scrips.

Comment: OK, that clarifies things a bit... What environment is the origin/destination of your commands? What do you use to ship commands over to be executed? What is the remote environment? What is your setup there (do you have a regular account, that you can access via `ssh` or `PuTTY` perhaps?

Answer (score -1):

You could run something like `expect` on your local computer to send `cmd1` and wait for it to finish before issuing `cmd2` etc.  You have to figure out a reasonable period to wait, or a specific output which indicate that the command is done, in order to write a proper Expect script.

Of course, `cmd1; cmd2; cmd3; cmd4` in one command will execute the commands in sequence, one after the other.